# Scrapy putting out empty JSON / CSV files

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm very new to scrapy and python and could really do with some help. I've got this code to work in command line. I can see it pulling out all the right information as it goes through the different pages.

My problem is that when I try to save the output of the script to a file it comes out empty. I have looked at lots of other questions on here but can't find anything that helps.

Here is the code

```
import scrapy
from urlparse import urljoin


class Aberdeenlocations1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "aberdeenlocations2"
    start_urls = [
        'http://brighthouse.co.uk/store-finder/all-stores',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        for p in products:
            url = urljoin(response.url, p)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        for div in response.css('div'):
          yield {
               title: (response.css('title::text').extract()),
               address: (response.css('[itemprop=streetAddress]::text').extract()),
               locality: (response.css('[itemprop=addressLocality]::text').extract()),
               region: (response.css('[itemprop=addressRegion]::text').extract()),
               postcode: (response.css('[itemprop=postalCode]::text').extract()),
               telephone: (response.css('[itemprop=telephone]::text').extract()),
               script: (response.xpath('//div/script').extract()),
               gmaplink: (response.xpath('//div/div/div/p/a/@href').extract_first())
                  }
```

I am then running this command on the above script

```
scrapy crawl aberdeenlocations2 -o data.json
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some python errors in your yield I think. Like this I get some data in output:

```
import scrapy
from urlparse import urljoin


class Aberdeenlocations1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "aberdeenlocations2"
    start_urls = [
        'http://brighthouse.co.uk/store-finder/all-stores',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        for p in products:
            url = urljoin(response.url, p)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        # not sure why this loop is there
        for div in response.css('div'):
          yield {
               'title': response.css('title::text').extract(),
               'address': response.css('[itemprop=streetAddress]::text').extract(),
               'locality': response.css('[itemprop=addressLocality]::text').extract(),
               'region': response.css('[itemprop=addressRegion]::text').extract(),
               'postcode': response.css('[itemprop=postalCode]::text').extract(),
               'telephone': response.css('[itemprop=telephone]::text').extract(),
               'script': response.xpath('//div/script').extract(),
               'gmaplink': response.xpath('//div/div/div/p/a/@href').extract_first()
                  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Very appreciated. 

The loop is in there because of me copy-pasting different snippets together to try and get things to work so it has become a bit Frankenstein...

When I run the code you've made I get this error message:

`File "C:\Users\nikja\aberdeen\aberdeen\spiders\aberdeenlocations1.py", line 25, in <module>
    response.xpath('//ul/li/a/@href').extract()
NameError: name 'response' is not defined` 

Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Ignore the above comment. I've got it to work - the issue was that I had a duplicate Python File which had the same name which was causing the error. **You've solved my issue thanks!**